# How to manage stateful components in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I know that it is considered the best practice to have stateless components most of the time and the logic and state of that components should be kept in their parent. But the problem here is that if another parent component needs to have the same child components (or some of them), we have to recreate the same logic and state in that parent component too. So this is why we have state and stateful components, so that they could manage their own state and manage their own behaviour to avoid code duplication.

A good example of such a component is a [Controlled input component](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html#controlled-components). So far so good, but I need to have a way to control its state from a parent component, if for example I want to empty its value or autocorrect it. For this we have [componentWillReceiveProps()](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentwillreceiveprops).

```
class Input extends React.Component {
  static propTypes = {
    value: PropTypes.string,
    label: PropTypes.string,
  };

  static defaultProps = {
    value: '',
    label: '',
  };

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { value: props.value };

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    this.setState({ value: nextProps.value });
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({value: event.target.value});
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <label>
        {this.props.label}:
        <input type="text" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange} />
      </label>
    );
  }
}
```

So the `Parent` passes down a new value to its `Input` component and `Input` updates its state in its `componentWillReceiveProps` function. The problem here is that now we have to keep `Input` value in the `Parent` all the time. Because if we don't pass it down, then it will be taken from `Input` `defaultProps` and it will be impossible to modify `Input` value anymore.

What I would like to achieve is that if the `Parent` passes down the value to `Input`, then `Input` should use it and update its state. But when it doesn't, but passes down other props, then `Input` should keep its own value.

The thing is that it is impossible to tell in `componentWillReceiveProps` function whether the prop was passed as `undefined` or it was equal to the value of the `defaultProps`. A possible solution could be not to use `defaultProps` at all. But not using such a core feature of ReactJS seems wrong to me.

Comment: Looking at the example you've linked to on the React website it would appear that state is kept at the form component (parent) level and a input element simply receives props from the form.

Comment: I would recommend not having state in the input component at all. Just pass an onChange handler and a value from the parent to the Input component. When the input changes, call the onChange handler (from the input component) with the new value and let the parent do whatever it wants with it.

Comment: `Input` component is just an example. If I make it stateless then I would have to recreate its logic in all other parent components that use it and this is bad. I very like the idea of [composition](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html). So I can add functionality by wrapping one component into another.